# Class zipArchive class not found

Tags: php, zip, gzip

**Case**

Download zipped bulk documents

**State**

Php info return this:

```
    PHP Version => 5.5.16

    ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
    gzip compression => enabled
    bzip2 compression => disabled (install pecl/bz2)
    Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

**What's happening**

This line :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // is giving the error of Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

And this one :

```
extension_loaded('zip')  //is giving null
```

**Question**

Is there a library Which should be included in the code like require_once(library) ?
What is going wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)

Comment: Code formatting for reading

Comment: Formatted the list to "paragraph title"

Comment: How did you installed php? On which operating system?

Comment: Which distribution? Debian? Ubuntu? Centos? ...

Comment: You should have a separate **zip** table with the text *Zip: enabled*. The extension is bundled by default since PHP/5.3.0 but I suppose your packager might have chosen to split it into an optional package. That's why we need to know how you installed PHP.